# Dismissing a Popover created by a segue on iOS 9

Tags: ios, uipopover, uipresentationcontroller

There are a lot of questions and answers on Stack Overflow about this but they are just valid for iOS 8 and before.

iOS 9 deprecated a lot of things and the answers on SO did not work anymore.

Said that, I am presenting a popover by performing a segue like this

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myPopover" sender:self];
```

This segue is created between the current viewController and the viewController used by the popover. There is no button involved. The popover is anchored to a view.

The problem is that on `prepareForSegue:identifier`

```
[segue destinationViewController]
```

is a `UIViewController` and

```
[[segue destinationViewController] popoverPresentationController]
```

is the new `UIPopoverPresentationController` and this object does not offer a dismiss api anymore.

Instead, we are supposed to use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

to dismiss the popover but this has no effect for me.

My situation is this: I have a popover with a text field. I want to dismiss the popover if the user hides the keyboard.

So I did this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and then

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but this has no effect at all.

I have also tried to create an unwind segue inside the popover viewController and call that from the presenting view controller but that makes the app crash.

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719306/dismissviewcontrolleranimatedyes-completionnil-not-working-for-ios-device

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468698/how-to-detect-when-a-popover-is-dismissed-in-ios-9

Comment: @iAnurag - the question you mention tells me nothing about what I have asked... "how to **dismiss**" not present.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - `self presentingViewController` gives me nil inside the popover view controller.

Comment: What class is your `keyboardWillHide:` method in?

Comment: Just tried it and it all seems to work perfectly. What is your view controller hierarchy (navigation controllers, etc.)? Are you properly calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` on the same view controller that presented the popover? Make sure there isn't a mixup between child view controller and navigation controller. You can also log the popover view controller's `presentingViewController` to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried it and it all seems to work perfectly.

- What is your view controller hierarchy (navigation controllers, etc.)?
- Are you properly calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on the same view controller that presented the popover?
- Make sure there isn't a mixup between child view controller and navigation controller.
- You can also log the popover view controller's `presentingViewController` to check.